# Issue new identities using comoposer-rest-server explorer with multi-user authentitacion

Tags: rest, docker, docker-compose, acl, hyperledger-composer

Does somebody knows how could I issue new identities using the composer-rest-server explorer? I've done the multi-user authentication and I cannot find a way to issue new identities.

Rest api logs:

```
Unhandled error for request POST /api/system/identities/issue: Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":20,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]
```

CA peer logs:

```
Checking to see if caller 'jdoe' is a registrar
2018/04/19 15:33:03 [DEBUG] Registration of 'test' failed: : scode: 401, local code: 42, local msg: 'jdoe' is not a registrar, remote code: 20, remote msg: Authorization failure
2018/04/19 15:33:03 [INFO] 172.19.0.8:51394 POST /api/v1/register 401 42 "'jdoe' is not a registrar"
```

Thanks! :)

Gerard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an optional parameter on the `composer identity issue` command to enable the ID (in this case jdoe) to have the privilege to issue other Identities.

The optional parameter is `-x` and the whole command is documented here: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest//reference/composer.identity.issue

I assume you followed the Google OAuth2 tutorial, where joe doesn't get the privilege

Comment: Yes, I've followed the Google OAuth2 tutorial, thanks for your answer, it worked! :)

Nevertheless, can we do it through the API? My objective is to build a test application where I can manage two types of users, admins and normal users. 
Do I have to build my own API in order to manage the identities issue rights?

Comment: Yes - as answered on Rocket Chat this can be achieved on the REST API endpoint `/api/system/identities/issue` by including the option `"options" : {"issuer" : true}` in the JSON data for the request.